# How can I perform a calculation for values inside CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I have a 'large' CSV file that I would like perform a calculation for one of the 'values' in it.

Extract from csv:

```
id,active,source,SourceId,latlngs,type,area,fir,Designator,MultipleCode,Name
142,0,N,4204260,"-17652,-32400;-17656,-32229;-17762,-32230;-17730,-32400;",R,"",SBRJ,,"","Area 1              "
264040,0,N,10083080,"29900,8400;29900,10800;29650,10800;29650,8400;"," ","R  ","Area 2 "
```

and the files continues for many Mbytes...

I'm doing the following:

```
import csv

with open('example.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row["Name"],end=',')
        f= row["latlngs"][0:-1].split(sep=';')
        for a in f:
            b= a.split()[0:]
            print (b)
```

as a result I get:

```
Area1 ,['-17652,-32400']
['-17656,-32229']
['-17762,-32230']
['-17730,-32400']
Area 2       ,['-17652,-32400']
['-17656,-32229']
['-17762,-32230']
['-17730,-32400']
```

Now that I have the `latlngs` next to the Names, I need to divide each one of the values within the list, for instance; `[-17652,-32400'] / 600` to have `-29.42 -54` or `['-17656,-32229'] / 600` to have `-29.426 -53.715`.

While doing this, is where I fail.
I have tried many things, after the last line of code I added.

```
for a in f:
    a.split(',')[0:]
    x = a[0:].split(sep=',')
    try:
        y = int(x[0])/600
        z = int(x[1])/600
        print (y,z)
    except ValueError as e:
            print (e)
```

But there, the one that gets calculated is the very last `latlngs` from the CSV file.

Extract from the output:

```
Area 500,['32390,-8980']
['31920,-9230']
['31930,-9290']
['32510,-12220']
['33090,-18000']
['32510,-23780']
['31330,-29680']
['31330,-29700']
['30620,-32380']
['30620,-32380']
['31070,-32730']
['31530,-33060']
['32260,-30310']
['33480,-24220']
['33480,-24210']
['34090,-18090']
['34090,-17900']
['33480,-11780']
['33470,-11740']
['32870,-8720']
['32390,-8980']
53.983333333333334 -14.966666666666667
53.2 -15.383333333333333
53.21666666666667 -15.483333333333333
54.18333333333333 -20.366666666666667
55.15 -30.0
54.18333333333333 -39.63333333333333
52.21666666666667 -49.46666666666667
52.21666666666667 -49.5
51.03333333333333 -53.96666666666667
51.03333333333333 -53.96666666666667
51.78333333333333 -54.55
52.55 -55.1
53.766666666666666 -50.516666666666666
55.8 -40.36666666666667
55.8 -40.35
56.81666666666667 -30.15
56.81666666666667 -29.833333333333332
55.8 -19.633333333333333
55.78333333333333 -19.566666666666666
54.78333333333333 -14.533333333333333
53.983333333333334 -14.966666666666667
```

What I can see (in my limited view) is that I cannot understand why the value that gets calculated and displayed is the last one instead of each one of them.

The main goal is:
Once I have the result from those calculations, I would store them into a new CSV file, the 'end goal' would be to have sth like:

````
Name,latlngs
Area 1, "53.983333333333334 -14.966666666666667,53.2 -15.383333333333333,53.21666666666667 -15.483333333333333,54.18333333333333 -20.366666666666667,55.15 -30.0"<br/>
Area 2,"49.833333333333336 14.0,49.833333333333336 18.0,49.416666666666664 18.0,49.416666666666664 14.0"<br/>```
````

Comment: What (would/)do you do with the values after you've divided them by 600?

Comment: Once I have the result from those calculations, I would store them into a new csv file, the 'end goal' would be to have sth like:
Area1, "53.983333333333334 -14.966666666666667,53.2 -15.383333333333333,53.21666666666667 -15.483333333333333,54.18333333333333 -20.366666666666667,55.15 -30.0"

Comment: The problem is you put that last `for a in f:` loop in the wrong place (which is why it's using theery last `latlngs` from the CSV file. It need to be indent and done inside the *first* `for a in f:` loop up where you are reading the file.

Comment: You should put your final goal, including the example of the output CSV file, into your question. Comments may be ignored or deleted altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will edit the main body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want to reformat the style of the coordinates in the CSV file (and divide the values by 600), this might work:

```
import csv


with (open('example.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as infile,
      open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile):
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=['area', 'coordinates'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        # Split coordinates and divide by 600
        coordinates = [[int(value)/600 for value in coord.split(',')] for coord in row['latlngs'][:-1].split(';')]
        # Format coordinates into new format
        coordinates = ','.join(f"{coord[0]} {coord[1]}" for coord in coordinates)
        writer.writerow({'area': row['Name'], 'coordinates': coordinates})
```

which has an output of

```
Name,latlngs
Area 1 ,"-29.42 -54.0,-29.426666666666666 -53.715,-29.60333333333333 -53.71666666666667,-29.55 -54.0"
```

Comment: and it worked an absolute beauty...thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't divide a list: the division will operate on the list, not on the individual items inside the list. For that functionality, you would need to use NumPy (in which case, you may also start using Pandas for working with tabular data).

In pure Python, using the CSV modules, something like this can work:

```
import csv

with open('example.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Name'], end=', ')
        coords = row['latlngs'][:-1].split(';')
        for coord in coords:
            print(coord)
            lat, lon = [int(item) for item in coord.split(',')]
            lat /= 600
            lon /= 600
            print(lat, lon)
```

You would then need to store each separate lat and lon (possibly in a list) for each row, then store that list of lats and lons in another structure for the whole file. Or write them directly to a new file.

Comment: Note: for the second row, I obtain an incorrect Name, since your example data appears to be incomplete for the second row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at liberty to use the `pandas` library, you can try something like this.

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame


def transform(lat_long: str):
    # -17652,-32400;-17656,-32229;-17762,-32230;-17730,-32400;
    raw = [ll.split(",") for ll in lat_long.split(';') if ll]
    new_lat_longs = [(float(lat) / 600, float(long) / 600) for lat, long in raw]
    new_lat_longs = ";".join([f"{lat}, {long}" for lat, long in new_lat_longs])
    return new_lat_longs


df: DataFrame = read_csv('sorted.csv', index_col=0, header=0)
df["new_latlngs"] = df["latlngs"].apply(transform)
df.to_csv('transformed_new.csv')
```

This basically, loads the CSV, applies a transformation function to every latlng column in all rows, and sets the value as a new column.

The new CSV will look like

```
id,active,source,SourceId,latlngs,type,area,fir,Designator,MultipleCode,Name,new_latlngs
142,0,N,4204260,"-17652,-32400;-17656,-32229;-17762,-32230;-17730,-32400;",R,,SBRJ,,,Area 1              ,"-29.42, -54.0;-29.426666666666666, -53.715;-29.60333333333333, -53.71666666666667;-29.55, -54.0"
264040,0,N,10083080,"29900,8400;29900,10800;29650,10800;29650,8400;", ,R  ,Area 2 ,,,,"49.833333333333336, 14.0;49.833333333333336, 18.0;49.416666666666664, 18.0;49.416666666666664, 14.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. More than including adding the values to the new/updated CSV, I am aiming to create a separated csv file where I will have:
Name,latlongs<br/>
Area 1,"-29.42 -54.0,-29.426666666666666 -53.715,-29.60333333333333 -53.71666666666667,-29.55 -54.0"<br/>
this is because the latlongs from that new CSV have to be formated in that way to be picked up ( or copy pasted) into a diff app